# Add metatags to a file when copying to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

following this article: [Powershell script to transfer files from local folder to document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208425/powershell-script-to-transfer-files-from-local-folder-to-document-library)

is it possible to add more properties to a file when uploading from a file share to sharepoint,

Forr example، I have an Enterprise Keyword column, and if the file is being copied from a folder X to sharepoint I want it to have the enterprise keyword "X" added as a property to that file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

First add a column in SharePoint document library for example you named the column "Keyword"

Use the following updated script to update managed metadata column:

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

#Script settings
$webUrl = "http://vs-server12"

$docLibraryName = "Documents"
$docLibraryUrlName = "Shared%20Documents"
$localFolderPath = "C:\temp\Docs4SharePoint"

#Open web and library
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl

#Getting the managed term
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
foreach($item in $termStore.Groups)
{
    if($item.Name -eq "Marketing")
    {
        $group = $item
    }
}

$termset = $group.TermSets["Marketing Initiative"];
foreach($t in $termset.Terms)
{
    if($t.Name -eq "X")
    {
        $term = $t
    }
}

$docLibrary = $web.Lists[$docLibraryName]
$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item $localFolderPath)).GetFiles()
ForEach($file in $files)
{
#Open file
$fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()

#Add file
$folder = $web.getfolder($docLibrary.rootFolder.URL)

write-host "Copying file " $file.Name " to " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl "..."
$spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
$spFile.Item["Keyword"] = $term                
$spFile.Item.Update();
write-host "Success"

#Close file stream
$fileStream.Close();
}

#Dispose web

$web.Dispose()
```

NOTE:

I had to change `$folder =  $web.getfolder($docLibraryUrlName)` to `$folder =  $web.getfolder($docLibrary.rootFolder.URL)` to make the script work.

Comment: Will this work both for Managed Metadata and Choice columns alike?

Comment: It will work for Choice column but not for Managed Metadata

Comment: I'm confused now.. in my original question I was asking about Enterprise Keywords, which IS a managed metadata column.. no? so for that it won't work?

Comment: maybe possible combining the following articles:

https://seyedketabchi.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/accessing-taxonomies-from-powershell/ and https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20554/powershell-update-column-with-managed-metadata

Comment: Yes merging these articles will work.

Comment: @SazMifsud I have updated my answer to include the script

Comment: @SazMifsud did this work?